# jassimp.dll: The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: java, c++, dll

I've been working on the same problem for the past ~4 days: getting JAssimp to work (an Assimp port for Java). Before I ask this question, if ANYONE has got this to work and can provide any files, please do. I am so tired of messing with this.

Anyways, I've compiled two .dlls: jassimp.dll and assimp.dll (jassimp needs assimp.dll to work).

I've placed those in my project directory, and tried to run the project (obviously linking with jassimp.jar, built with ANT)

I get an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: D:\VB2013Projects\jassimpfinal\Debug\jassimp.dll: The specified procedure could not be found
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1937)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1855)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at jassimp.Jassimp.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at opengltutorials.Mesh.loadMesh(Mesh.java:131)
    at opengltutorials.Tutorial.init(Tutorial.java:124)
    at opengltutorials.Tutorial.main(Tutorial.java:238)
```

I checked the dependencies using dependency walker, and jassimp.dll shows like this:

[image]

What's happening here, and how can I fix this?